# Black screen with system information

Tags: recovery-mode, hardware, prestigio-multipad

I have Prestigio Multipad WIZE 3047 3G. On Tuesday evening something went wrong and I got black screen with some system checks (see picture). Tablet warmed very fast and didn't respond to pressing power button. Pressing reset button caused rebooting that fixed problem.

What could it be and how prevent such problem?

Android 4.4.2 (manufactor's OS version w/o root, JB or something else)

<sub>Click image to enlarge</sub>

[image: Hardware Tests]

Comment: That screen reminds me of hardware tests option available under some stock Recoveries.

Answer (score 0):

Something caused a system crash and the tablet rebooted to try and selftest, similar to what happens when windows "Blue Screens".

Without the logs which we don't have now we can't determine why it crashed or how to prevent it. It could be an unreliable memory region, power delivery fault or just simply a bad bit of code.

If it doesnt happen again then don't worry, not a huge deal.